# Is "deem" punctual or stative?

Tags: word-meaning

Is "deem" punctual or stative? Does this verb express a momentous action or a state of being?

I was taught that "when" goes along well with punctual verbs, while "after" goes well with stative ones. For example,

> **When** he was able to crack the Trident code, that was *[quickly, right away, immediately]* **deemed** by many as his major achievement in his deciphering career. (punctual,
>   the action of deeming took place almost momentously)
>
> **After** he was able to crack the Trident code, **that was deemed** by many *[for many years after that, in the following years]* as his major achievement in his deciphering career. (stative,
>   the action of deeming was lasting for a long period of time after that
>   point)

So, should I use "when" or "after"? In other words is "deem" here expressing a momentous action or a lasting state?

Comment: deem=considered, to be deemed, to be considered. HIs cracking the code was deemed to be or considered to be. Same thing.

Comment: @Lambie: Is "was considered" punctual or stative? (Please, check my edits in my question examples)

Comment: Basically, you are asking for editing. You can look up examples on the internet. deem is usually used in contracts or very formal writing. I don't know what punctual means. You mean: momentary action, not momentous. :) However, I suspect you speak a Romance language where ponctuel/al means once off or from time to time.

Comment: You are presenting a false choice. Either *when* or *after* can be used. (Depending on more context than is presented here.) However, you should not be using *that* after a comma. Either remove the comma or replace *that* with *which*.

Comment: @JasonBassford - _"However, you should not be using that after a comma"_ - Are you sure about that? "That" in my sentence is a reference to the fact/event/act described in the sentence before the comma. In other words, the meaning is this: he performed a great act of breaking the code - it was this act of his that was deemed by many as his greatest achievement. Removing the comma or replacing _that_ with _which_ will change the meaning and render my sentence incomplete.

Comment: @Lambie _I don't know what punctual means_ - I don't speak any of the Romance languages. I used the word _punctual_ in the sense it was used by supporter Colin Fine in his answer to one of my questions. Please, check it out: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/215489/using-thought-to-imply-a-single-instance-of-thinking-not-recalling

Comment: @brilliant I'm positive. You can start an independent clause or sentence with *that* (using it as a pronoun to refer to a previous clause or sentence), but if that's the case here, then your use of a comma is a comma splice. No matter how it's interpreted, the use of a comma (without a conjunction) followed by *that* is not correct. In fact, both of your current sentences are actually just sentence fragments. Because of how you've punctuated them, they are left as incomplete thoughts. Even using a dash instead of a comma would work. The accepted answer wisely rephrases them to remove *that*.

Comment: @JasonBassford - You said earlier: _Either remove the comma or replace that with which_ - I don't understand how replacing _that_ with _which_ makes things clear. You just read it with _which_: "When he was able to crack the Trident code, which was deemed by many as his major achievement in his deciphering career..." First of all, the sentence now is not finished. Secondly, now it means that it is not his act of breaking the code that is deemed by many as an achievement, but the code is deemed by many as an achievement! But that's nonsense then and totally not the point I want to get across.

Comment: @JasonBassford _You can start an independent clause or sentence with that (using it as a pronoun to refer to a previous clause or sentence), but if that's the case here, then your use of a comma is a comma splice_ - Wikipedia says that a comma splice is a "the use of a comma to join two independent clauses": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice But in my case the first clause ("When he was able to crack the code,") is an adverbial clause, which is a dependent clause and not an independent one (it cannot stand alone).

Comment: @brilliant I am not going to get into a long debate in these comments. I could address all of these points, but it would take an actual answer—and it wouldn't be an answer to the main question you asked. The point is that your use of *that*, in both sentences, is not correct.

Comment: @JasonBassford Well, of course, if you don’t want to explain the points you’ve presented, you don’t have to. But as for me, merely knowing that something is wrong is not as useful as knowing also why it is wrong. The problem is, the more I was looking into the points you were presenting, the more I was confused by them. So I still need some clarification. Therefore, I will be asking the community questions about them. Here is the first question:  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/217151/the-precise-meaning-of-comma-splice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your primary question:  "Deem" is a *stative* verb.  It represents an opinion of someone at some particular point in time.  Although that opinion may continue to be valid, we do not say that someone *continues* to deem [somebody] to be [some characteristic].  You "deem" once, and then you are done "deeming".

That being said, I don't see a reason why this should matter whether you use "when" or "after".  Either may be used:

> **When/After** he cracked the code, experts **deemed** him to be a genius

The main problem with your sentence is that it is confusing.  It seems you wants some achievement to be the subject, but you write the sentence with the person himself as the subject. You have to match the subject to the characteristic.

I would instead start with a gerund phrase, and avoid the when/after issue entirely:

> **Cracking the Trident code** was [quickly, right away, immediately] deemed by many as **the major achievement of his career**.

Otherwise, if he himself is the subject, then he has to be deemed some characteristic that can be ascribed to a person.

> Soon after he cracked the code, **he** was deemed by many to be **the preeminent expert on decryption techniques**.

Other notes:

1. Avoid unnecessary adverbs.  Unless it's really important to mention how rapidly he was deemed", there is no need to include "quickly" or "immediately" in your writing, especially in the middle of the verb.  If you must include it, put it at the start of the sentence (as in my use of "soon" above).
2. I'm not sure if "deciphering" is the right term to describe a career, or rather, the general field already has the name **cryptology**.  Someone who works in cryptology *ciphers/deciphers*, or *encrypts/decrypts*, on a regular basis.

Comment: _It seems you wants some achievement to be the subject, but you write the sentence with the person himself as the subject. You have to match the subject to the characteristic_ - Can you, please, tell me if the following sentence is also confusing: "When the USSR sent first man into space in April 1962, that was considered by many as the first big achievement of the Socialist system"

Comment: _You have to match the subject to the characteristic_ - Here is one line from the Beatles song "That means a lot" (https://www.thebeatles.com/song/means-lot):  "When she says she loves you that means a lot" Here the subject (the act of saying) is not matched to the characteristic either. So, does that line from the song also sound confusing?

Comment: @brilliant  The *act* of "sending a man" into space is considered a "brilliant achievement".  Nothing wrong there.  Similarly, the act of "saying she loves you" *means a lot* (to you).  Again, nothing wrong.  You're matching subject to characteristic.   But it would be just as valid to make it about the *person*, if you wanted:  *"The **first man** the USSR sent into space was considered a **great hero**"* , *"**She** who says she loves you, **means a lot** to you"*

Comment: So, just to make things clear, you are saying that there is nothing confusing in "When the USSR sent first man into space in April 1962, that was considered by many as the first big achievement of the Socialist system.", and there is nothing confusing in "When she says she loves you that means a lot.", right?